# Advice on writing Video Player for Windows Mobile

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, mobile

I wanted to develop a video player for Windows mobile using C#; can anyone direct me in correct direction to look for all the help I would be requiring in this topic. Please send me links and your comments in this direction. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Save yourself a lot of trouble and use the OpenNetCF Media Player Controls from 
http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/Controls/MediaPlayerControls/tabid/264/Default.aspx

The alternative is A LOT of pInvoke.

If you really, really must do this yourself and cannot use any third party libraries you will probably want to host media player as an activeX control. Details of how to do this at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446515.aspx.
Be warned. This [is](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/4e35bad0-9eae-4ed8-ada5-bd249411fa1f/) [not](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxcompact/thread/e2b1780d-7841-462f-9cfe-0a72d7781d5f/) [straight](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/6d218e96-5a25-4b21-9ddb-d3a82acee1c9) [forward](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/3b57e45f-153e-4340-b5a9-a9b08c192b4d). Use the built in media player or third party controls if you possibly can.

Comment: Note that there is a bug in the MSDN ActiveX Hosting code.  A patch is available here: http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2008/08/14/BugInMSDNActiveXHostingCode.aspx